# OR (or any logical operator) together many columns in R

Tags: r

As explained above, I would like to OR multiple columns and was hoping to do so without having to explicitly reference the columns (`d$a | d$b | d$c`), but rather with an array of column names (`c(a,b,c)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(df <- data.frame(a = c(T, F, T, T), b = c(T, T, F, T), c = c(F, F, T, T)))
#       a     b     c
# 1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
Reduce(`|`, df)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
Reduce(`&`, df)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: And on part of the df: `Reduce("|", df[,c('a','b')])`

Comment: Pet peeves of mine: use backticks, not quotes, around the operator (\`|\` etc.). R accepts quotes but that’s idiotic: we want a function *name* here, not a character string, and those are different things.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you want to take `|` rowwise.

```
d = data.frame(a = c(TRUE, FALSE), b = c(FALSE, FALSE))
#       a     b
# 1  TRUE FALSE
# 2 FALSE FALSE
```

So the expected result here is `c(TRUE, FALSE)`.

You can use `any` over all columns in `d`:

```
apply(d, 1, any)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Over named columns in `d`:

```
apply(d[c("a", "b")], 1, any)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Performance considerations:

```
library(microbenchmark)
df <- data.frame(a = c(T, F, T, T), b = c(T, T, F, T), c = c(F, F, T, T))
microbenchmark(
  Reduce = Reduce(`|`, df),
  apply = apply(df, 1, any))
# Unit: microseconds
#    expr    min      lq     mean  median       uq     max neval cld
#  Reduce  6.597  8.2275 11.83880 10.0730  13.4080  36.246   100  a 
#   apply 56.423 59.9425 79.86748 66.8265 105.7645 178.409   100   b
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd actually prefer `Reduce` here.

Comment: Why? `any` *is* a `Reduce` over the \`|\` operator (just implemented more efficiently, probably). Although, true, the `any` has to be applied rowwise whereas \`|\` can naturally vectorise.

Comment: Yes, in concept. `Reduce` is actually faster. On the other hand, `apply` with `any` is probably more readable and idiomatic.

Comment: Nice of you to add the benchmark. That difference isn’t even subtle! Who would have thought?